# Why does casting A<B> to A<C> sometimes succeed, even though B and C are unrelated?

Tags: swift, macos, generics

I'm using the Contacts framework, and I've got code that loops over all values of a CNContact and does this:

```
if let label = value as? CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber> {
    let v: CNPhoneNumber = label.value
    NSLog("v = \(v), type = \(type(of: v))")
}
```

Mostly, it prints output like this:

```
v = <CNPhoneNumber: 0x1234567890a0: countryCode=us, digits=7775551212>, type = CNPhoneNumber
```

but it also prints output like this:

```
v = foo@example.com, type = __NSCFString
```

On other cases I've tried, though, the placeholder type is relevant as part of the type:

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1). Type :help for assistance.
  1> class C<T> { }
  2> let c1 = C<Int>()
c1: C<Int> = {}
  3> let c2 = C<String>()
c2: C<String> = {}
  4> c1 as? C<String>
$R0: C<String>? = nil
```

What's the rule here?  Why is a `CNLabeledValue<NSString>` getting successfully cast to a `CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>` here?  And how can I accurately detect this type, then?

EDIT: Here is a complete program:

```
import Cocoa
import Contacts
let me = try! CNContactStore().unifiedMeContactWithKeys(toFetch: [CNContactEmailAddressesKey as NSString])
let value = me.value(forKey: CNContactEmailAddressesKey)
if let array = value as? [CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>] {
    for item in array {
        if let phone = item as? CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber> {
            let v: CNPhoneNumber = phone.value
            NSLog("v = \(v), type = \(type(of: v))")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide full testable code?

Comment: If `if let array = value as? [CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>]` succeeds, you know _for a fact_ that `for item in array` will assign `item` a `CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>`. There is no need for the second `if let` test. I am surprised the compiler does not warn about this.

Comment: matt: The compiler does warn (though those are not terribly reliable warnings: I've seen cases where it warns "cast always fails", when in fact it always succeeds, or vice versa), but I don't think it's important here.  If you change `value as? [CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>]` to `value as? [Any]` it compiles with no warnings, but gives the same unusual output.

Comment: matt: Basically, I couldn't come up with a non-silly example that demonstrated the actual problem.  Every example either worked as expected (`class C<T>`), or was needlessly complex (my own program), or looked silly in isolation (what I posted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CNLabeledValue` is an Objective-C class. Objective-C doesn't have true generics. When Swift arrived so called "lightweight generics" where introduced to improve the interoperability with Swift. Those only help the compiler to type check, but at runtime the extra type information is lost (Basically [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure)). This is why you get any type in your first example.

In your second example you define real Swift generics. There the types are not erased and so they are available at runtime and the types can actually be checked.

Comment: Found this in https://swift.org/migration-guide/ as a limitation on generics: "If an Objective-C generic class is used in a checked as?, as!, or is cast, the generic parameters are not checked at runtime."

Comment: This seems like a pretty big "gotcha"!  I assumed that when a cast succeeds in Swift, that the type is accurate at that point.  I'm going to have to re-examine all my casts to see what language the type was written in -- ouch.